# Merge multiple stdout/stderr into one stdout

Tags: process, merge, terminal, subprocess, stdout

I have a development stack with multiple processes running: web server, auto-testing, compilation in background etc. All of these are basic command line commands such as `node app.js` or `lein midje :autotest`.

Is it possible with one script to run all these processes in "background" and **merge their outputs into one stdout** (that is: to show it on the screen in terminal)?

One of the problem with easy bash solution that I found (using &) is that on Ctrl+C the background processes are obviously kept alive, which is not possible desirable.

I have tried adding trap `'kill $(jobs -pr)' SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT` but this doesn't seem to work reliably on OS X - surprisingly the node processes get killed, but the java ones are still living after the script exits (via Ctrl+C).

I can use any scripting language. I would prefer pure bash or JS, but Python or Ruby are OK too.

I would also like the ANSI escape colouring to be preserved in the merged output.

Comment: Could the Java processes be catching the signal? What happens if you hit Ctrl-C when one of them is in the foreground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `multitail` utility. It not only allows you to tail log files, but also output of arbitrary CLI programs (`lein run`, `lein midje :autotest`, ...).

Example:

`$ multitail --mergeall -cT ANSI -l "lein midje :autotest" -cT ANSI -l "lein ring server-headless"`

`Ctrl-C` than kills all processes which are being tailed.

If you are OSX user you can install `multitail` using `brew install multitail` (assuming that you already have homebrew installed - if not, see http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/)

In order to get more info about multitail configuration you might read `man multitail`. There are also usage examples at http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/index.php